# Redirecting log output to HTML text area

Tags: java, apache, jsp, logging

I am currently in the process of writing a web application using JSP and have logging setup being written to a file during the app's running lifetime. The log information in this case is very important to the user and I would like to display it somehow. At first I thought of using some kind of actionListener on the Logger object itself and using a scriptlet inside the JSP to append text into a Text Area element but I'm not quite sure if that would work. Is there an easy or known way to do this? Any feedback and help is greatly appreciated. Right now I am using the regular apache Logger object but am certainly open to using outside libraries such as Log4j or other options to achieve what I need.

Am I not able to do this? The text area would need to be updated without actually refreshing the whole page each time there is info written by the logger. If this is not able to be done, would a popup for processing be advisable? This would probably be done with a popup, perhaps with JSwing but this may look ugly.

Comment: Doing this might be a security issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered doing some simple periodic ajax polling? Here is a small example using jQuery that posts to some jsp and then calls another javascript function to update your textArea:

```
function doPoll(){
    $.post('ajax/log.jsp', function(data) {
        updateTextArea(data);  // process results here
        setTimeout(doPoll,5000);
    });
}
```

A simple but maybe quite blut possibility would be to have your controller read the produced logfile when ajax posts to it and return the latest changes (or the whole log).

EDIT: developerwjk was a bit faster :) If the log is important, keep it somewhere in your database. Then in the post retrieve the log messages and pass them back to the ajax.

Comment: Dealing with time intervals and updating the text area element with something from the file when it changes is something I had considered. I am unfamilar with ajax poling but it looks like it could definitely be a valid solution. Thank very much for this idea. I'll post back again.

Comment: Since I am using a Java Logger object in my class, I may think about using a StringBuffer to append log sentences to as I go and inside the JSP write a scriptlet to check if the buffer size is greater than before update the text area, if not then do not update the text area.

Comment: Take into consideration that usually controllers do their work only when some requests are handed to them. One has to come up with ways to handle the events that happen on the serverside between requests.

Answer (score -1):

Keep track of whatever it is you're logging in a database with some kind of key, then after the page loads in the browser do an Ajax request to a servlet that will return the log text, and in your Javascript set the text into the textbox when the Ajax response is received.